# How do I set Filestream from an fileupload control?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

This is my code and I can't seem to get the file I have in my FileUploadCotrol into the FILESTREAM.

```
 // The buffer size is set to 2kb
int buffLength = 2048;
byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
int contentLen;

// Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
FileStream fs = fileInf.OpenRead();

try
{
    // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
    Stream strm = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();

    // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
    contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

    // Till Stream content ends
    while (contentLen != 0)
    {
        // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
        strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
        contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
    }

    // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
    strm.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

It seems the I should be using the Fileupload control to do the from my website, yet it seams strange that the control creates a stream and not a filestream.  Yes I am FTPing a file.

Comment: what type is 'fileInf'? and what type is 'reqFTP'?

Comment: ultimately you're going to need to use a MemoryStream I think.  but need a little more info

Comment: FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(filename);</ br>
FtpWebRequest reqFTP;</ br>
// Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + sFtpId + "/" + fileInf.Name))</ br>  I pass in the filename I get from the fileupload control.

Comment: Wow, nothing yet this morning.  I might have to go with Microsofts two-step approach of having the control put it on the server then FTP from there?  Yuk, will have to call ISP and see if I have room for large files.

Comment: Well Currently doing the two step process still need to test with a 100mg file.

Comment: sorry... I dont have an FTP to test this against... never got to test the result below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample method that takes the two types we are targeting, `FileInfo` and `FtpWebRequest`, as arguments and streams data between them.  I believe this will work.

```
    void UploadFileToFtp(FileInfo file, FtpWebRequest req)
    {
        int buffLength = 2048;

        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenRead()))
        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                while (reader.PeekChar() > 0) writer.Write(reader.ReadBytes(buffLength));
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will give it a try, I did get it to work doing the 2 step process, but I would really like to avoid storing anything of this size there.

Comment: Getting an Error ----  The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'.
Parameter name: chars   It puts the file up on the ftp server but it is damaged.

Comment: I was able to eliminate the error by adding to the open ",Encoding.ASCII".  But the pdf file I am up loading is still trash.

Comment: The File size on the server is 82KB and the PDF should be 613.6 KB